# Activity constructor is not assigning value

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor, appcompatactivity

```
class CosmosNewsDetailActivity() : AppCompatActivity(), ArticleAppearanceActionListener {
private var newsKey = -1L
private var newsItem: NewsGetAllResponse.NewsGetAllResponseItem? = null

constructor(key: Long, item: NewsGetAllResponse.NewsGetAllResponseItem?) : this() {
    newsKey = key
    newsItem = item
}
```

newsKey is always at value -1, how do I instantiate this class with these parameters without using intent extras

I can see the value for key in the constructor is correct but never assigned to newsKey

Comment: There is no circumstance that I can think of where Android would use an activity constructor that took parameters. Where did you learn about this approach?

Comment: I was just copying my knowledge working with fragments and was hoping the activity could do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only `Activity` constructor that will be used is a zero-argument constructor. Please do something else for getting data to this activity (e.g., `Intent` extras, shared data managed by a repository) or get rid of this activity (have it be another fragment or composable used by an existing activity).